# How does the drop-down calendar in the panel work? New event button does not do anything

Tags: indicator, 13.10, panel, calendar, lightning

I just found out that in 13.10 there's an "add event" button in the calendar that drops down from the panel. Yet i couldn't figure out how to make it work? 
For me clicking it does nothing. Does it integrate with Google calendar or Lightning at all? 
What do I have to do to make it work? Or is this button just there to make it look functional?

I appreciate any help. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install evolution for the add event option in the calendar to work.
Run:
`sudo apt-get install evolution`

Comment: oh ok thanks! wow... why would they have a button that only works if you install new software? at least they should integrate it with the google calendar webapp..

Comment: Calendar is integrated to EDS. Any event exists in EDS(evolution-data-server) appears in calendar drop-down menu. EDS is installed by default. You can create an event in eds by programming or syncing google-calendar with with eds using syncevolution OR using a gtk/gui app Evolution. Evolution is just the font-end,it is not necessary.

Comment: great. I have used evolution as a gui to set up the sync with gcal and then uninstalled it. How could I access EDS without installing evolution first? Does that work via the Terminal?